# Rotating an object around an axis in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a simple thing in unity: rotate an object around an axis. But I'm missing something, my object just goes in the downward direction, instead of rotating around the axis.

This is my update function:

```
this.transform.RotateAround(new Vector3(1,0,5), new Vector3(0,1,0), 10 * Time.deltaTime);
```

where (1,0,5) is the center of rotation. My object is at position (0,0,0).
The object just moves down, instead of rotating.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe add a gif or a link to video of what's happening.

Comment: This line of code looks correct. Are you sure you don't have another line or another script that moves your object. Does it stop moving when commenting this line?

Comment: Other possible problem is if the transform has a child object that has a different position and OP actually wants to rotate that object, not its parent.

Comment: I think RotateAround works with world coordinates so if your GameObject is far from that (1,0,5) it will move on a big circle

Answer (score 1):

I think it can solve your problem. This is the script you need:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateObj : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        // rotate to its own axis
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value)); 

        // rotate about axis passing through the point in world coordinates
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, 1.0f); 
    }
}
```

and this is your unity configuration:

[image]

And it rotates around itself (randomly) and `Vector3.zero` coordinates

[image]